# I want to show more listings on click

Tags: php

I'm doing a real estate thing for a class project and I have reached a hurdle.

```
<? 

    echo '<section id="listings">';
    echo "<h1>Browse our selection</h1>";

    $i = 0;
    $limit=5;

    foreach($data as $d){


        echo "<article>"; 
        echo "<div class='photo'> <img src='db/images/" . $d["img"] . ".jpg' alt='Nancy Stone Realty'> </div>";
        echo "<h5>$<strong>" . $d["price"] . "</strong><em>month</em></h5>";
        echo "<h3>" . $d["address"] . "</h3>";
        echo "<h4>" . $d["city"] . ", <em>FL. " . $d["zip"] . "</em></h4>";
        echo "<dl>
                  <dt>Bedrooms</dt>
                  <dd>"  . $d["bed"] . "</dd>
                  <dt>Bath</dt>
                  <dd>" . $d["bath"] . "</dd>
                  <dt>Pets</dt>
                  <dd>" . $d["pets"] . "</dd>
             </dl>";
        echo "<p>" . $d["description"] . "</p>";
        //echo "<a href='#' class='btn btn-primary btn-mini paulund_modal'>MORE</a>";
        echo " <a class='btn btn-primary btn-mini' href=?action=properties&ID="    .$d["ID"].">More</a>";
        echo "</article>";

        if (++$i == $limit) break;
    }


    echo "<form id='next5' method='POST' action=''>";
    echo "  <input type='submit' name='More'  value='More Houses'>";
    echo "</form>";

    if (isset($_POST['More'])) 
    { 
       $limit=$limit + 5;
       echo "$limit";
    } 

?>
```

I am limiting how many are showing in chunks of 5. I would like when I press 'more' that the limit increases by 5. I print the limit at the end to see if it is working and it shows 10 after first click and all future clicks so I don't think that it is working. I am also thinking that I may be setting the limit to +5 after the click and then back to default of 5 after that.

What is the proper way of doing what I am trying.

Thank you.

Comment: It is better to use ajax to load more data. You need to pass params offset and limit to your php code.

Comment: Why not retrive all results and use JavaScript to hide/show however you want?

Comment: Mostly, because  I am learning this as I go. I saw that ajax is a way to do this thing but I have yet to mess with it. It has been added to my list of things to learn.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<? 

    echo '<section id="listings">';
    echo "<h1>Browse our selection</h1>";

    $i = 0;
    $step = isset($_REQUEST['step'])? $_REQUEST['step']: 0;
    $limit=5 + $step*5;

    foreach($data as $d){


        echo "<article>"; 
        echo "<div class='photo'> <img src='db/images/" . $d["img"] . ".jpg' alt='Nancy Stone Realty'> </div>";
        echo "<h5>$<strong>" . $d["price"] . "</strong><em>month</em></h5>";
        echo "<h3>" . $d["address"] . "</h3>";
        echo "<h4>" . $d["city"] . ", <em>FL. " . $d["zip"] . "</em></h4>";
        echo "<dl>
                  <dt>Bedrooms</dt>
                  <dd>"  . $d["bed"] . "</dd>
                  <dt>Bath</dt>
                  <dd>" . $d["bath"] . "</dd>
                  <dt>Pets</dt>
                  <dd>" . $d["pets"] . "</dd>
             </dl>";
        echo "<p>" . $d["description"] . "</p>";
        //echo "<a href='#' class='btn btn-primary btn-mini paulund_modal'>MORE</a>";
        echo " <a class='btn btn-primary btn-mini' href=?action=properties&ID="    .$d["ID"].">More</a>";
        echo "</article>";

        if (++$i == $limit) break;
    }


    echo "<form id='next5' method='POST' action=''>";
    echo "  <input type='hidden' name='step'  value='".($step+1)."'>";
    echo "  <input type='submit' name='More'  value='More Houses'>";
    echo "</form>";

    if (isset($_POST['More'])) 
    { 
       echo "$limit";
    } 

?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Every time a page loads in PHP *(which happens upon submission)* it loads the variables like they were when the page was written. Of course you could do something like:

```
session_start();
if(!isset($_SESSION['limit']))$_SESSION['limit'] = 0;
if(!isset($_SESSION['inc']))$_SESSION['inc'] = 0;
$_SESSION['limit'] += 5;
```

Later in you code, its like:

```
if(++$_SESSION['inc'] === $_SESSION['limit'])
```